# XLL doesn't properly load

Tags: windows-xp, excel-2007, xll

I've got a XLL Addin and I'm trying to run it under Excel 2007 XP without VBA installed.
My addin is well registered (OPEN key as /R "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyAddin\myAddin.xll" in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Options). When debuging, I see that DLLMain is called... but not xlAutoOpen (neither others xlSomethings functions): my UDFs are thus not registered (it was done in xlAutoOpen).
Do I miss something ? Do I absolutly need VBA installed ? If yes, is there another way to avoid installing it ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  When I installed Office I deliberately did not install any Excel Add-Ins -- it looks like this actually cripples the loading of any future Add-ins.

After running the Office installer again and choosing to install the 'built-in' Add-Ins, I finally hit my xlAutoOpen breakpoint.