# XLL Add-in menu won't auto load

Tags: c, api, menu, add-in, xll

I wrote a small XLL Add-in (VS2010 VC++/Excel 2007) containing a menu.
It's correctly registered (seen with the Add-In Manager) but the menu doesn't show up when I open my excel workbook (a .xlsb). I have to again load it manually (Excel Options -> Add-Ins -> Excel Add-In -> Go -> Browse) each time i open the workbook.

I have no trouble with another XLL (VS2010 VC++/Excel 2007) which has NO menu (just User Defined Functions).

I was once able to have the menu showing up on double-clicking the XLL (but not anymore).
The XLL is a Debug version only (I think I have the same problem with a Release version)

I have been googling around for some times, but found no definite answer.

Any answer, return of experience, hints etc ... would be greatly appreciated
Thanks
N

PS: Am not in the same case as [XLL doesn't properly load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151633/xll-doesnt-properly-load). My xlAutoOpen works fine

Answer (score 1):

There is an example showing how to add and delete menus here: http://nxll.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/10265#144179

It uses http://nxll.codeplex.com to simplify writing add-ins.

Comment: Thank you for this link. I guess it's a more modern version of http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178474 of which I based mine.